Use PyBind11 with CMake and MSYS2 and MinGW
I want to use Pybind11 together with CMake and MSYS2.
I installed pybind11 with the command
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pybind11

on MSYS2.
Then I created the two files example.cpp and CMakeLists.txt in the same directory (my working directory).
example.cpp is copied from this tutoriel
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:
   # Nous voulons un cmake "récent" pour utiliser les dernières fonctionnalités
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

# Notre projet est étiqueté hello
project(example)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG)

# pybind11 method:
pybind11_add_module(MyModule1 example.cpp)

# Python method:
Python_add_library(MyModule2 example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyModule2 pybind11::headers)
set_target_properties(MyModule2 PROPERTIES
                                INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ON
                                CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET ON
                                VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN ON)

I have created this CMakeLists.txt file with the help of this tutorial
Then I ran the commands:
mkdir mingwbuild
cd mingwbuild
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"

and I get the error:
    cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/cc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Software/MSYS2/usr/bin/c++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: D:/Software/Python/python.exe (found version "3.11.1") found components: Interpreter Development Development.Module Development.Embed
-- pybind11::lto disabled (problems with undefined symbols for MinGW for now)
-- pybind11::thin_lto disabled (problems with undefined symbols for MinGW for now)
-- Found pybind11: D:/Software/MSYS2/mingw64/include (found version "2.11.1")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (target_link_libraries):
  The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
  the target "MyModule2".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target
  must be either all-keyword or all-plain.

  The uses of the keyword signature are here:

   * D:/Software/MSYS2/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:3400 (target_link_libraries)



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/PythonBindC++/buildmingw3/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Informatik/NachhilfeInfoUni/KadalaSchmittC++/PythonBindC++/buildmingw3/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I am expecting some file like example.exe should be created, and then I just want to go to the directory of example.exe and run a python script like this one:
import example
print( example.add(3,4))

Not sure whether I need to install anything on the Python side with Pip
like
pip install pybind11

Any help appreciated!

No, I think that this does not answer my question. I completely changed my question. The library is now found, but different errors are there.

It's usually discouraged to completely rewrite the question, but I guess since nobody else answered/commented, it's ok in this case. This error looks better, but I don't have a Windows machine right now to debug it.

Looks like the script pybind11NewTools.cmake has been written for modern version of CMake, which supports IN_LIST operator in if command. Try to specify newer version in cmake_minimum_required command. E.g. 3.3, where IN_LIST operator has been introduced.

Thanks a lot! I set the CMAKE version to 3.3. and that error disappeared. I have edited the question and get now a new error I don't know how to resolve.

I finally solved the problem:
The CMakeLists.txt must look like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

# Notre projet est étiqueté hello
project(example)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG)

# pybind11 method:
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

Then running
mkdir buildmingw
cd buildmingw
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
mingw32-make 

produces a file
example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd
